# Django - get the running server absolute url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there any way I can set a variable in `settings.py` to point to the current url ?

For example, If I'm running a debug server on `http://0.0.0.0:8080` or `http://127.0.0.1:9000` or `https://www.mydomain.com`.

I basically need to generate full path for image fields returned from an API. The trick is that I don't always have a request object (`POST` on `DRF` for example - The request does not exist in the context when `transform_xxx` is called).

Appreciate any help with this.

Comment: I don't get the question completely - yes, of course you can set a variable in settings.py. You could also create environment specific settings ("settings_local.py"). You could also store the domain name in an environment variable and read it where you need it.

Comment: I want to populate the variable on server startup. e.g in `settings.py` set `HOST_URL=get_host_url_somehow()`

Comment: Without the request object, there is no reasonable way. You should set it in the regarding context (site framework, OS environment, local settings etc.)

Comment: It does for GET, but apparently for POST it dosen't. My problem is that i'm using django as an API and I need to return the full path of an image field (usually it will be rendered by django directly in the template or the file will be served from the same origin - This is not the case).

Comment: I take it back. I forgot to pass on the context to a nested serializer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the `contrib.sites` framework you can pull the site URL from there.

There's a [good example in the docs for when you don't have access to the request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#hooking-into-the-current-site-from-views):

```
current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
if current_site.domain == 'foo.com':
    # Do something
    pass
else:
    # Do something else.
    pass
```

Hopefully that's what you need.

**UPDATE**: I see from the comments that used correctly you would have the request available. I'll leave this here answering the challenge for when you don't.